# Addition and Subtraction of Random Numbers

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to make a simple math game which is made of 3 forms. The first form is the title screen which has a button to start the game. When the button is pressed it will make form 2 visible. Form 2 will generate 2 random numbers and either a “+” or a “-“ symbol and begin a timer. The user then inputs the answer into a text box and clicks the “check answer” button, which will display either the “correct” or “incorrect” label. I want this to repeat 5 times and the final time will display form 3 which will show the total time taken and number of correct answers.

So far in my first form I have:

```
Public Class startForm
Public randomNumber As New Random()

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Me.Hide()
    questionForm.Show()

    questionForm.num1.Text = randomNumber.Next(1, 100)
    questionForm.num2.Text = randomNumber.Next(1, 100)
    questionForm.mathSymbol.Text = randomNumber.Next(1, 10)

    If questionForm.mathSymbol.Text = 1 Then
        questionForm.mathSymbol.Text = "+"
    ElseIf questionForm.mathSymbol.Text = 2 Then
        questionForm.mathSymbol.Text = "+"
    ElseIf questionForm.mathSymbol.Text = 3 Then
        questionForm.mathSymbol.Text = "+"
    ElseIf questionForm.mathSymbol.Text = 4 Then
        questionForm.mathSymbol.Text = "+"
    ElseIf questionForm.mathSymbol.Text = 5 Then
        questionForm.mathSymbol.Text = "+"
    Else
        questionForm.mathSymbol.Text = "-"
    End If

End Sub

End Class
```

And in my second form I have:

```
Public Class questionForm

Public count As Integer = 0
Public ans As Integer


Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    If mathSymbol.Text = "+" Then
        Convert.ToInt32(num1.Text)
        Convert.ToInt32(num2.Text)
        ans = num1.Text + num2.Text
    Else
        ans = num1.Text - num2.Text
    End If

    If answerBox.Text = ans Then
        correctLabel.Visible = True
    Else
        incorrectLabel.Visible = True
    End If

End Sub

End Class
```

This causes the answer to always be displayed as "Incorrect" so what should I do to fix it? I am also having trouble getting the timer to work.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried to debug your program? How looks "answerBox.Text" like?

Comment: Turn on Option Strict; `Convert.ToInt32(num1.Text)` doesnt do what you think it does and `num1.Text - num2.Text` is also problematic

Comment: Also, you say you are having trouble getting the timer to work. What did you try? I don't see where you handle the timer. You could check [this](http://vb.net-informations.com/gui/timer-vb.htm) out, it may help you.

Comment: I'd also like to point out, in addition to the great comments above, that while you are setting the label you want to show to visible, you are not resetting the other label's `.Visible` property to false. Depending on the layout of the labels on your form, either you will see both of them (if they are side by side) or only one of them (if they are positioned one on top of the other).

Comment: rather that toggling the Visible prop on 2 labels, you could have just ONE and change the message to display as needed

Comment: Thank you for the quick responses. I have now set the other answer labels to false as suggested by RianBattle and removed both "Convert.ToInt32" lines. The answer box is now working correctly but I don't know how to repeat the process so that another set of numbers is generated in place of the old ones.

Comment: You have two choices. Either you add a refresh button or you could suspend the current thread for the number of seconds you'd like, thanks to [System.Threading.Thread.Sleep](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t.aspx) and then generate another set of numbers.

Comment: To avoid code duplication, I'd suggest you to move your number generation code from inside your Form 1's button click event to the Form 2. Put it in a procedure and call it in Form 2's load event. Also call it in the refresh button code's or after the thread suspension. If anything isn't clear, ask.

Comment: I have moved the number generation code into the second form as suggested and called it in the load event, but now I have a problem with the "Incorrect" label always appearing again. [Here is the new code](http://i.imgur.com/nkjd0zU.png) Thanks.

Comment: I highly recommend you to use breakpoints while debugging. It stops the program where you put your breakpoint and you can check your variables values. Anyways, the problem is you're adding two strings together (`num1.Text` and `num2.Text`). So if you try to add "83" and "3", you will get 833, instead of 86, since you're adding two strings. Simply convert them to integers before performing the sum operation, like this: `ans = CInt(num1.Text) + CInt(num2.Text)`, and that should work as you want.